# If the same message is sent to Alice and Bob who are using different public keys, how can somoene following the channel find $m$

Tags: cryptography

Alice and Bob are using different public keys, Alice is using ($N_{1,2}$) and Bob ($N_{2,2}$). A message, $m$ is sent to both of them using their RSA systems. It is also true that $N_1$ and $N_2$ are relatively prime.

Can anyone explain how Eve can now find $m$? I'm quite sure it has an application of the Chinese remainder theorem.

Comment: You have to use the Chinese remainder theorem to find m^2modN1N2. Does anyone know how to find this?

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the [Håstad's Broadcast Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_Attack#H.C3.A5stad.27s_Broadcast_Attack). If all public exponents are equal to $e$, Eve can recover $m$ as soon as the number of parties is greater than or equal to $e$.

Suppose Eve collects $c_1$ and $c_2$, where $c_i \equiv m^2\pmod {N_i}$, $i = 1, 2$. By the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), Eve may compute $c \in \mathbb Z_{N_1 N_2}$ such that $c \equiv m^2\pmod {N_1 N_2}$. $c = m^2$ holds over the integers, so Eve can compute the square root of $c$ to obtain $m$.

Comment: Thank you, Do you know exactly how she uses the Chinese remainder theorem to do this ?

Comment: Thank you, Do you know exactly how she uses the Chinese remainder theorem to do this ? is it using some for of euclids algorithim  @Stavros

Comment: It's just an application of CRT. We know that $N_1$ and $N_2$ are relative prime. Then, for the given sequence of integers $c_1, c_2$, there exists an integer $x$ solving the system of the following simultaneous congruences: $x \equiv c_1\pmod {N_1}$ and $x \equiv c_2\pmod {N_2}$.

Comment: The requirement for Hastads Broadcast attack state that m < N1 and m<N2. However in my question the only condition is that m < N1. Any ideas on how to overcome this @Stavros Mekesis

Comment: Are you sure that the only given is $m < N_1$? Beware of the fact that if $m > N_2$, you won't get the exact $m$ back when you decrypt $c_2$.